# Trying to display burger menu dropdown behind navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, overflow, z-index, display

I have spent countless hours trying to figure out why my dropdown that is opened/closed by a burger menu icon click is sitting in front of the navbar even though I have specified z-indexes, overflows and positions. This issue is only happening on the **MobileNav** component below. MobileNav consists of a burger icon and the actual dropdown. Once the burger icon is clicked, the dropdown will either close or open. Currently It is displaying above the nav component and I am having a very hard time figuring out why. Any help will be much appreciated.

Vid to see the dropdown's behavior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOBnb6r_RN4&ab_channel=TylerOreskey

The dropdown is supposed to come out from the bottom of the navbar and close up into the bottom of the navbar.

**Navbar Component**: Renders **MobileNav** component

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);
  const dropdownToggleHandler = () => setShowDropdown(!showDropdown);
  const dropdownClosedHandler = () => setShowDropdown(false);

  return (
    <header
      className={classes.Navbar}
      style={{
        position: props.passedNavbar ? "fixed" : "relative",
      }}
    >
      <nav className={classes.MobileNav}>
        <MobileNav
          allNavigationRefs={props.allNavigationRefs}
          scrollToDiv={props.scrollToDiv}
          open={showDropdown}
          closed={dropdownClosedHandler}
          dropdownToggleHandler={dropdownToggleHandler}
        />
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default memo(Navbar);
```

**CSS** file for **Navbar component**: z-index is not working in here.

```
.Navbar {
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: hsl(213, 27%, 15%);
  border-bottom: #00bfff 3px solid;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .DesktopNav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .MobileNav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**MobileNav** component

```
const MobileNav = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.MobileNav}>
      <DropdownToggle clicked={props.dropdownToggleHandler} />
      <Dropdown open={props.open} allNavigationRefs={props.allNavigationRefs} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MobileNav;
```

**CSS** file for **MobileNav** component

```
    .MobileNav {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

**Dropdown** component: (This is displayed above the **Navbar** component and I cannot get it to be behind the navbar component).

```
const Dropdown = (props) => {
  let attachedClasses = [classes.Dropdown, classes.Close];

  if (props.open) {
    attachedClasses = [classes.Dropdown, classes.Open];
  }

  return (
    <div className={attachedClasses.join(" ")}>
      <NavigationItems allNavigationRefs={props.allNavigationRefs} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

**CSS** file for **Dropdown** component: z-index is not working in here.

```
.Dropdown {
  background: hsl(212, 87%, 3%);
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 400;
  display: block;
}

.Open {
  transform: translate(0, 25%);
}

.Close {
  transform: translate(0, -75%);
}
```

Comment: A screenshot of the Issue would be helpful.

Comment: Youtube link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOBnb6r_RN4&ab_channel=TylerOreskey

Answer (score 0):

You are confused on how z-index works.
Consider each level in your tree as a layer.
lets say that `Navbar` is layer 0, `MobileNav` is then layer 1, and its children are on layer 2.

By default z-index is calculated among children of the same layer. This is true when the `position` attribute is on default `static`. When you alter this to `relative` you can instruct which layers are going to interuct with each other in a more immediate way.
Having 500 z-index on Navbar will make no sense to MobileNav. It is not his sibling, it's his child.

Here is a possible solution if you can alter the DOM tree

```
 <header
      className={classes.Navbar}
      style={{
        position: props.passedNavbar ? "fixed" : "relative"
      }}
    >
      <nav className={classes.Navbar}>
        <DropdownToggle clicked={props.dropdownToggleHandler} />
      </nav>
      <MobileNav
        className={classes.MobileNav}
        allNavigationRefs={props.allNavigationRefs}
        scrollToDiv={props.scrollToDiv}
        open={showDropdown}
        closed={dropdownClosedHandler}
      />
    </header>
```

and here is an answer if you can alter the CSS

```
.Navbar {
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: hsl(213, 27%, 15%);
  border-bottom: #00bfff 3px solid;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

...

.Dropdown {
  background: hsl(212, 87%, 3%);
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: So all I need to do is pull MobileNav out from being a child to Navbar in order to use z-index?

Comment: I am not if this suits the rest of your project but here's a sample (updated reply)

Comment: Worked in a way. Dropdown has a gap at the top and is under a lot of my content down the page, but it does come out from the bottom of the nav and goes back into the bottom of the nav. I think I can manage from here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was able to get this resolved with a few tweaks in addition to your ideas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help